# How to read multiple lines input as single input using Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

input file :

```
>sp|P31946|1433B_HUMAN 14-3-3 protein beta/alpha OS=Homo sapiens GN=YWHAB PE=3 SV=3
MTMDKSELVQKAKLAEQAERYDDMAAAMKAVTEQGHELSNEERNLLSVAYKNVVGARRSS
WRVISSIEQKTERNEKKQQMGKEYREKIEAELQDICNDVLELLDKYLIPNATQPESKVFY
>sp|P62258|1433E_HUMAN 14-3-3 protein epsilon OS=Homo sapiens GN=YWHAE PE=1 SV=1
MDDREDLVYQAKLAEQAERYDEMVESMKKVAGMDVELTVEERNLLSVAYKNVIGARRASW
RIISSIEQKEENKGGEDKLKMIREYRQMVETELKLICCDILDVLDKHLIPAANTGESKVF
```

Expected Output :

> sp|P62258|1433E_HUMAN 14-3-3 protein epsilon OS=Homo sapiens GN=YWHAE PE=1 SV=1
>       MDDREDLVYQAKLAEQAERYDEMVESMKKVAGMDVELTVEERNLLSVAYKNVIGARRASW
>       RIISSIEQKEENKGGEDKLKMIREYRQMVETELKLICCDILDVLDKHLIPAANTGESKVF

Code written so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

fh = open("test_seq")
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith('>'):
        if re.search('PE=1',line):
             print line
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the input data in general? Giving one example tells nothing.

Comment: I want to parse the data.. so that output file contains both header and sequence. I am only able to get the header line with my code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Append the lines together and then they will function as a single string.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
with open("test_seq", 'rb') as fh: 
    print_line = False
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if re.search('PE=1',line):
                print_line = True
            else:
                print_line = False
        if print_line:
            print line
```

Comment: I want to parse the data.. so that output file contains both header and sequence. I am only able to get the header line with my code. thanks

Comment: Are you sure my code doesn't also give the sequence?